# Updating binding with jQuery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a sortable list of fixtures that is populated from an `observableArray` using the `foreach` binding.  One of the parameters in each fixture in the array is `position`.

That position reflects the order that the fixtures are sorted in. By default when the fixtures are inserted using `foreach`, the position numbers are in the correct order, but when you sort the list by dragging the items, the position number is updated using jQuery:

```
$( "#picks" ).sortable({
    revert: true,
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    containment: 'parent',
    axis: "y",
    handle: '.dragHandle',
    update: function() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= $('#picks li').length; i++) {
            $('#picks li:nth-child('+i+')').find('span.num').text(i);
        }
    }
});
```

So, the position numbers do change, but since the numbers are updated without referencing the observable, the observable itself isn't updated.  My question is, how can I update the observable using the update function tied to the jQuery sortable.

I do not want make the number an input, so using an input with a value binding was not an option!

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/tsnolan23/rswq1kjt/16/)

Comment: Try notifying all the subscribers of fixtures observable array manually inside the update method ,like this "fixtures.valueHasMutated()"

Comment: The jQuery function is outside my viewModel, so I cannot reference `fixtures`. Should I move the jQuery function inside the viewModel to try?

Comment: I attempted that route, but it does not have the desired effect: http://jsfiddle.net/tsnolan23/rswq1kjt/17/

Comment: You don't need to move the jquery code inside the view model,instead create a instance of view model like this `var vm= new view model(); ko.applybindings (VM)` and at the same time refer the observables outside VM using `vm` like this `vm.fixtures.valueHasMutated()`.

Comment: Either way, not the desired effect, it seems to put whatever item is first to #1 but not the others

Answer (score 0):

You need a [binding handler for your sortable](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable). If you mess with the DOM outside of a binding handler, you have problems like this. The author even provides links to some demo fiddles at the bottom of the github page.